# How can i send cursor position to tcp server?

Tags: javascript, c#, php, sockets

I have this code on my website.
What i want is to send the value of the cookie to c# server,it works but how can I continuously send the updated cookie.I want if it is possible to send it with php.xv is the name of the cookie that is made with X coordonate of cursor.

```html
<html>


<script type="text/javascript">
var x;
var y;

window.onload = init;
function init() {
 if (window.Event) {
 document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
 }
 document.onmousemove = getCursorXY;
}

function getCursorXY(e) {
    
 
    
    
 x = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
 y = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
 
 var days=0.5;
 var name ="xv";
 var domain="xxxxm";
 var value =x;
 var path ="/";
  if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        var expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/; domain=xxxxx";

}
</script>


<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Send an AJAX request to your web server which contains the data you need. Please be aware that sending every single mouse movement to the web server could overwhelm it with requests especially if you have many users. You can choose to either capture mouse position at intervals or just send a big chunk of data at intervals.

Comment: Thanks for replay,but i really don't know to do AJAX requests to get a cookie value.

Comment: Baby steps, bud. Go learn how to do a basic AJAX request. Once you've achieved that then sending a cookie's value will be blindingly simple. There is zero reason for me to teach you how to do an AJAX request; there are hundreds of code samples on Stack Overflow alone.